# Android driver issue

Tags: appium

I am new to mobile automation with appium.i am getting error message "The constructor AndriodDriver (Capabilities) refers to the missing type Capabilities ".

```
driver=new AndriodDriver (new URL("127.0.0.1:4723"), 
Capabilities);
```

Comment: driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

Comment: Hi tried it facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below links. Those might be help full

http://toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/download-and-install-nodejs/

http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/09/appium-tutorials.html

Comment: I have gone through the links done set up.I am not able find any reference to this..

Comment: Can you please post the code that you are using. So that i can say what is the reason for the error

Comment: AndriodDriver driver; DesiredCapabilities cap=DesiredCapabilities();//setting some capabilities driver=new AndriodDriver (new URL ("127.0.0.1:4273"),cap)

Comment: please add some capabilities like device name and port as shown in the link - http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/10/appium-run-first-android-automation.html